# Always show group in select directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a select directive where there can be two types of elements in the list, displays and groups (which contain displays). Most of the time the list will contain both displays and groups and each are categorized by their respective type (good). The problem is when only one type of object exists in the list, the group label is not shown. How is the user supposed to know if they're looking at just displays or just groups?

Code:

```
<select class="form-control"
        name="selectItem"
        ng-model="item"
        ng-options="item as item.name group by item.getType() for item in availableTransferItems"
        required> 
</select>
```

Comment: "How is the user supposed to know if they're looking at just displays or just groups?" : Show him

Comment: Its just a drop down in a modal pop up.. I don't really want to qualify the type in line with the name of the item. I want that to be the header of the group regardless of the number of different types present

Comment: please post demo in Fiddle or else